# Using Alamofire in a command line OS X app (Xcode 7) - code encapsulation?

Tags: swift, macos, xcode7, alamofire

I'm trying to figure out how to use Alamofire in a command line app.

I can't use frameworks, so I've added the Alamofire source code into the app (so no import statement) and I'm able to directly reference the request() and other methods.

Is there a cleaner way to encapsulate Alamofire or is this a limitation in Swift 2.X at the moment?

Comment: I'll be happy to know if you found a solution to this problem!

Comment: You can use it with Swift Package Manager https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/building-a-command-line-tool-using-the-swift-package-manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who gonna need it here is the solution.
If you don't have the file xcodeproject please generate

```
$ swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

You may need to fix the Deployment Target

[image: xcode deployment target]

Now time to add the Alamofire

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SuiteTest",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "5.0.0")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/JohnSundell/Files", from: "4.0.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "SuiteTest",
            dependencies: ["Files", "Alamofire"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "ASuiteTestTests",
            dependencies: ["Assure-SuiteTest"]),
    ]
)
```

I hope I have helped anyone who has the same problem :)